# Headering X-csrftoken

Tags: php, javascript, http-headers, csrf

I need create a log-in script to some form.
The problem is that the log-in required a X-scsrf-token.
I have the token itself, but the problem is that I cant find a way to send this parameter.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious candidate I've spot in the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) documentation is [setRequestHeader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29):

> **setRequestHeader()**
>
> Sets the value of an HTTP request header.You must call
>   setRequestHeader() after open(), but before send().
>
> ```
> void setRequestHeader(
>    DOMString header,
>    DOMString value
> );
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `header` The name of the header whose value is to be set.
>   `value` The value to set as the body of the header.